# Why do I get 'CSRF Token Missing or Incorrect' error for Javascript Request

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, csrf

I am trying to create request in Javascript when a button is clicked but instead receive the error `Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.)`.
I have included `{% csrf_token %}` in the HTML template:

```
<form action="/cart" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="button" id="ordered">Place Order</button>
</form>
```

But am unsure if I have to include it in my Javascript request:

```
const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "/cart");

// send request
let data = new FormData();

items = localStorage.getItem(user + "items")
total = localStorage.getItem(user + "price")
data.append("items", items)
data.append("total", total)

request.send(data);
```

In my `views.py`:

```
def cart(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.get_json()
        print(f"{data}")

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
   else:
        return render(request, "cart.html")
```

Comment: I don't understand how your form and the JS code are linked in any way. Why would a token in a form somewhere on the site automatically add the csrf token to the JS request?

Comment: I am new to Django so can you please show me how to do so

Comment: Put your local storage attributes in hidden fields and get that values in your views as request.POST['items'] and you dont need to make any XMLHttpRequest(). If you use forms jst go through given link:  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/

Answer (score 0):

You have to send the CSRF token in every JavaScript request: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/csrf/#ajax

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this error, simply append CSRF token to your json data or add it to headers as shown below.

```
...
headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'}
...
```

or

```
...
headers: [{name: 'X-CSRFToken', value: csrfToken.value}],
...
```

Comment: wouldn't {{ csrf_token }} include the whole form field <input type="hidden"… etc.?